# FlyoutPage bar customization ( action bar?)

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-actionbar

I am trying to use the new `FlyoutPage`. I have set my Detail and Flyout pages.. now I want to customize the bar (with the hamburger menu), for both iOS and Android.

I need to change colors and add buttons etc.. Is there a way to do that with Xamarin.Forms (**without using shell..**) ? Or is there at least a sample of how to effectively do that with custom renderers?

I have tried to change the theme in my Android project to make changes, but with no great success.

Last but not least, could I remove the bar to create my own from scratch (but of course keep the flyout) ?

[The bar I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGsKU.png)

Comment: Could you share the minimum code you have so far? Curious to know why not Shell ?

Comment: @Cfun Its not easy for me to share the code. I need a navigation scheme that goes like so : NavigationPage -> navigationPage -> Tabbed page (pushed modally). On top of that I need a flyout everywhere.. Shell would be ideal to achieve this but we are already using the FreshMVVM framework and we depend on it. As far as I understand FreshMVVM does not support Shell. To achieve the aforementioned scheme I use a custom implemented navigationService and everything works fine. 
My only remaining problem is that i can not find a way (using Xamarin.Forms) to remove the bar created by the FlyoutPage.

Comment: @strat1 Hi, you could share another image to explain what your needs. It will be better to help you check whether it is possible.